# Integration issue

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am trying to solve $\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{x}dx $.

I read that it is a contour integral along the semi-circle of large radius in the lower complex plane. First, is there any justification for this, and second, does the integral then become $ -\int^{\pi}_{0} i d\theta$? This is what the text implies but I don't understand why it is $0\rightarrow\pi$ rather than $0\rightarrow2\pi$

Comment: The inner function is not defined for x=0.

Comment: @GautamShenoy That's not a real issue. Lebesgue's integral  makes sense for functions which are defined almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can't integrate it. If we assumed the integral exists (is real), then we'd be able to show that it is approximated by **any** real number through appropriate finagling. This isn't possible, so the integral doesn't exist.

Comment: I know that normally the integral wouldn't work it diverges. That is why I am converting it to a contour integral around a semi-circle, or is this just not possible?

Comment: If we can determine it through a contour integral, then the integral exists. This integral can't exist, so contour integrals won't get you there, either. Rather, a contour integral approach should also tell you that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left.\int\limits_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x}=\log|x|\right|_1^\infty\ldots\;\text{the integral diverges and so does yours}$$

Comment: Your method to show the divergence of the integral isn't correct, what you say for $\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{x}$?

Comment: True, but even if zero wasn't an issue it'd diverge. I shall edit, though.

Answer (score 0):

Make a graph and try to see why this integral is divergent, as stated by Don.
Sometimes graphs really help before embarking on an algebra spree.

Answer (score 0):

One of the important issues you face with this integral is that $$\infty - \infty$$ is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Lebesgue integral, this is not integrable as $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{|x|}dx=\lim\int_{1/n}^n\frac{1}{x}dx=2\lim \;2\log n=+\infty$$ by the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

If you see it as an improper integral, it diverges at $\pm\infty$ and $0^{\pm}$ for similar $\log $ reasons.

But you can make sense of this by considering the [Cauchy Principal Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value):
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}\int_{-1/\epsilon}^{-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx=0=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x}dx
$$
in this particular sense.

Comment: You don't need the monotone convergence theorem, this equality is the definition of the generalized integral.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane What do you call "generalized integral"? And yes, you need to do something to compute an integral. In this case, for instance, MCT is the minimal argument to see that the integral is infinite.

Comment: @julien How we define for example the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}$? is it not $\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_1^a \frac{dx}{x^2}$?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I know the definition of Lebesgue integral for nonnegative measurable functions...

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane DO you agree with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration)? If so, what do you propose? To look for the sup of $\int s$ for simple functions $0\leq s\leq |f|$...? We could. But the shortest way to actually prove $\int |f|=+\infty$ is to approximate by a nondecreasing sequence like I did. And use the Monotone COnvergence Theorem. Whether you like it or not. Otherwise, you will have to show me a method which is indeed faster and more elementary.

Comment: I agree with you, you can use if you want MCT, but what I try to explain that this is not necessary since equality $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1/n}^n\frac{1}{x}dx$ is the same definition used to calculate an improper integral, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral anyway you deserve +1 for this discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the +1. But I still disagree. I did not use the limit formula by definition. I used it by application of the MCT. This makes a big difference...Now again, the definition is the sup over simple functions. Are you saying that one should calculate the integral by approximation with simple functions? Of course not. The easiest way here is to apply MCT to a natural choice for a monotone sequence.

Answer (score 0):

"if we take x to be complex then we can move it from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ along a complex contour" The approx is given by, $ \frac{1}{(2\sqrt{y^{2}+x^{2}})^{0.5}}e^{-i \int \sqrt{y^{2}+x^{2}}}dx$

I realise that the only important thing is the exponential, so I taylor series this to get $e^{x+\frac{y^{2}}{2x}}dx$ then justified that due to the CPV theorem $\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}x dx \rightarrow 0$

and so we are left with $-\frac{iy^2}{2}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{x}dx$, ignoring the coeficients I then read that since x is complex it can be taken along a contour giving, $ \int^{\pi}_{0}\frac{1}{re^{i\theta}}rie^{i\theta} \rightarrow i\pi$, The trouble is that I also read that the limits could be to 2Pi and Im  not sure which is correct.